# RAISERROR Severity Level 16 IS rolling back transaction

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an issue with an AFTER INSERT UPDATE TRIGGER. Test code below. The problem is that when a transaction on this table is started it's rolled back.

After a lot of research online, it seems that everyone is in aggreance that that is NOT the case. Regardless, is there something on server side setting I'm missing?

I have also added the sp_settriggerorder() to the first trigger, naming the one in question last.

I've also noted that disabling the below trigger allows the transaction to complete.

Severity below 11 is not an option because it prompts an ugly warning in the client application to forces the user to "Expand" the selection.

Severity 11 though 16 all give me this issue.

```
USE [Test]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[co_bln_AfterIup]    Script Date: 06/29/2017 14:43:12 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[co_bln_AfterIup]
ON [dbo].[co_bln]
AFTER INSERT,UPDATE

AS

IF 1 = 1

RAISERROR('test error',16,1)
```

Comment: I am not following you. What is the problem?

Comment: I am also confused. Did you replace the actual trigger query with this error for testing? Are you sure the transaction was created and then rolled back or could it have been an issue with the update/insert itself and the RAISERROR is a red herring?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

1# Set SET XACT_ABORT OFF at the beginning of trigger execution

2# Do some DMLs(inserts/updates/deletes)

3# Set condition to fire RAISERROR with the message and severity under 18

4# Results would be committed transaction with raised error

**Longer answer**

There are two ways of handling errors in SQL Server ,one is using RAISERROR and another is using THROW. Which one you prefer would depend on a further explanation

Using throw you cannot specify severity, where as using RAISERROR you can
Using a higher(above 18) severity you can kill a user connection, which is not something you can do with throw

Also RAISERROR can be specified within explicit transaction (BEGIN/END) whereas
THROW cannot(Have to use  TRY/CATCH block).

Whats important here is something that connects these two error handlers is XACT_ABORT
By Specifying XACT_ABORT you are defining a transaction behavior

It is possible within a single transaction to have certain transaction that will fail, and some of them wont, depending on XACT_ABORT whether is ON or OFF , some of these succeeded transaction might be executed while others wont, which is usually something you dont want to do if you want to keep consistent database
More about XACT_ABORT you can read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql)

Now how is this related to your error handlers?

If you specify at the beginning of transaction SET XACT_ABORT OFF, your RAISERROR error handler wont rollback transaction, and whatever it is that you was doing before will be reflected to the database.
You have to options to prevent this , using explicit ROLLBACK transaction or Enabling XACT_ABORT

If you want to use TRY/CATCH block, and do some error handling you can use either one of these. Whenever you call RAISERROR or THROW you will be directly transferred to the CATCH block. However remember that even if you are in the catch block if XACT_ABORT is OFF and you are using RAISERROR with no ROLLBACK command, that transaction will be completed regardless.
If you use THROW it will be rolledback immediately

However XACT_ABORT on or off has no effect on THROW  handler and will be executed as expected( with rolling back all the changes)

Note also that even with XACT_ABORT OFF you can still rollback transaction using severity over 18

Therefore depending on what you are trying to achieve you can pick the one that suits you the best. Following the standard, THROW is the one to go, and its newer but if you wanted to just display the warning - back to **Short answer**

Answer (score 0):

You could surround the statements around the RAISERROR in a [TRY/CATCH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql) block if you don't want the RAISERROR to end the transaction. Or you could surround the INSERT/UPDATE statement that fires the trigger with a TRY/CATCH block.

From [RAISERROR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql) documentation (Remarks):

> When RAISERROR is run with a severity of 11 or higher in a TRY block, it transfers control to the associated CATCH block.

RAISERROR with a severity between 11 and 20 should transfer control to the catch block and should not necessarily abort the transaction if you don't write is as such.

Without seeing all your code, I'm guessing that some part of your program is rolling the transaction back as a response to the error raised in the trigger.